# update trigger success with compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to update a field in my table 2 depending on the value that is updated in a field from my table 1, using a trigger in oracle

```
create or replace trigger update_value
AFTER  update of field_1 on table_1
for each row 
begin
if(:New.field_1 = 'y') then 
update table_2
set field_2 = 'updated'
from table_1
where table_1.id = table_2.id

end if;
end;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: okey thanks for letting me know

Comment: Do `show errors` after running that, or query `user_errors`, to see what the actual underlying error is. What is the 'from table_1' supposed to be doing?

Comment: how do you show errors function

Comment: i thought i had to include the from because i was using fields from that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a trigger or any other stored PL/SQL code compiles with errors or warnings, you can see what the actual issue is by doing `show errors` (if youre client supports that; SQL*Plus and SQL Developer do); or you can query the `user_errors` or `all_errors` view for the appropriate object type and name, e.g.:

```
select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'UPDATE_VALUE';
```

The code you have will get `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" ...`. You don't have a semicolon after the update statement. If you add that you'll get `PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` because you can't have a `from` clause in an update statement (unless you have a subquery).

You don't need to refer to `table_1` directly; you're already using one `:NEW` variable, you just need to use another one:

```
create or replace trigger update_value
after update of field_1 on table_1
for each row 
begin
  if :NEW.field_1 = 'y' then 
    update table_2
    set field_2 = 'updated'
    where id = :NEW.id;
  end if;
end;
/
```